# Cannot assign event listeners externally (JavaScript). Event only fires once or not at all

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I can only assign events inline in html. The external script is being read as the functions housed in the script file are being executed.

I have tried assigning with the following methods:

- `$('link-1').on('mouseover', boldLink("link-1"))`
- `document.getElementById('link-1').onmouseover(boldLink("link-1")`
- `document.getElementById('link-1').addEventListener('mouseover', boldLink('link-1'))`

I have tried housing the event listeners in a `window.onload()` function as well. Sometimes it will fire once (even when the mouse has not been over the element), but otherwise it doesn't work.

I have tried moving my `<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>` to the end of the body. Currently it's in the header causing the same problems.

This is happening with all event types as well, not just the `mouseover` event.

Comment: You are assigning the result of _calling_ the function to the listener rather than a reference to the function.

Comment: Additonally to correct event handler reference, you've to put the script at the end of the body, or rather when using jQuery, enclose everything inside `$(document).ready(function () {});`.

Comment: Also you could just use CSS. Add a class to whatever elements need this and use `.thisclass:hover { font-weight: bold; }`.

Comment: To help wrap your mind around this: consider `alert( Math.sqrt(9) );` and think about the order in which things are evaluated / happen.

Comment: Thanks everyone, came right with all of this :)